# Android OpenStreetMap all streets within a bounding box

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap

I am writing an android application that needs to display street data only, stuff like max-speed etc. For this reason I want to extract all street data within a bounding box that I pass to the API of OSM.

Right now I get a rather large file that includes all the information that is stored in OSM. Is there a way to only query street data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the API documentation, the only parameters for bounding box are the left, bottom, right, and top. There appears to be no other way to retrieve regions of the map. You could get nodes individually by ID, but I think that will be tremendously useless.

You could implement your own webservice that hits the OSM api and strips it down, then hit your own webservice from your app. Extra work, but takes load off your mobile client.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking way too complicated. A webservice to proxy my request is exactly what I needed. Cheers!